# Impala : Error loading data using load inpath : AccessControlException: Permission denied by sticky bit: user=impala

Tags: hadoop, impala

All, 
I am new and trying few hands on use cases.
I have a file in hdfs and would want to load into impala table.

-- **File location on hdfs** : hdfs://xxx/user/hive/warehouse/impala_test

-- **Table** : CREATE TABLE impala_test_table
  (File_Format STRING ,Rank TINYINT, Splitable_ind STRING )
  Row format delimited
  Fields terminated by '\,'
  STORED AS textfile;

-- **Load syntax in impala-shell** : Load data inpath 'hdfs://xxx/user/hive/warehouse/impala_test' into table impala_test_table;
P.S : I am able to load it successfully with hive shell.

**ERROR**: AccessControlException: Permission denied by sticky bit: user=impala, path="/user/hive/warehouse/impala_test":uabc:hive:-rwxrwxrwx, parent="/user/hive/warehouse":hive:hive:drwxrwxrwt at ......

All permissions(777) are granted on the file impala_test.
Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I know it is too late to answer this question, but maybe it would help others searching in future.
refer to [HDFS Permissions Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html)
The Sticky bit can be set on directories, preventing anyone except the superuser, directory owner or file owner from deleting or moving the files within the directory. Setting the sticky bit for a file has no effect.

so to the best of my knowledge, you should sign in as hdfs super user and remove sticky bit by `hdfs dfs -chmod 0755 /dir_with_sticky_bit` or `hdfs dfs -chmod -t /dir_with_sticky_bit`

hope this asnwer helps anybody

Comment: Helped me. Thanks!